# How to see locale settings in action?

Tags: locale

I am tuning locale on my Linux box by changing variables like LC_*, LANGUAGE. There is no problem to find description of these variables. But how to see what actually changes? I mean not just output of `locale` command, but in practice. In other words I need test script for every locale-related variable.

Bash is preferable, python and perl are ok too.

Till now I have found this:

```
echo "(LANGUAGE=$LANGUAGE) Error message"                                                                                                                                                  
wc -q 2>&1
echo "(LC_TIME=$LC_TIME) Date: "
date +%x
echo "(LC_TIME=$LC_TIME) Time: "
date +%X
echo "(LC_TIME=$LC_TIME) Long date/time: "
date +%c
echo "(LC_NUMERIC=$LC_NUMERIC) Decimal/thousands separator"
printf "%'f\n" 1234567890
echo "(LC_COLLATE=$LC_COLLATE) Sorting order"
echo -e "english1\nEnglish2\nкириллица1\nКириллица2\n.dot" | sort
```

So, after switching for example, `export LC_COLLATE='C'` and `export LC_COLLATE='ru_RU.UTF-8'` I can see the difference in sorting order.

How to see effect of changing these variables?

- LC_CTYPE
- LC_MONETARY
- LC_MESSAGES
- LC_PAPER
- LC_NAME
- LC_ADDRESS
- LC_TELEPHONE
- LC_MEASUREMENT
- LC_IDENTIFICATION

Comment: This document describe all parameters in details: https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Locales.html.

Comment: There is no problem to find description of these variables. But how to see what actually changes in practice?